# Convert Byte[ ] To int in C#

Tags: c#

```
Byte[] byteSource = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FileInputPath);
int fileOffset = BitConverter.ToInt32(byteSource);
```

I am trying To Convert Byte array to int But its Showing Error "No overload method for Toint32"

Comment: If you read the entire error, it will tell you exactly what is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There is no overload of `ToInt32` taking single argument. [The method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) expects the array and the start index.

```
int fileOffset = BitConverter.ToInt32(byteSource, 0);
```

Comment: But There is One Problem After Conversion The Size of 'fileOffset' and 'byteSource' Are Diffrent. Why?

Comment: @RaaJivYadav, how different?

Comment: I mean Size of 'byteSource' = 33107618 i am receiving but after conversion 'fileOffset' not showing same value its size changed

Comment: @RaaJivYadav, from the link above: "The ToInt32 method converts the bytes from index startIndex to startIndex + 3 to an Int32 value.", so it just ignores the rest of the byte array. That's why the sizes are different. You cannot expect 33 million bytes to be converted to a single integer. If you want an int array - then this is a for loop you need

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is no method overload for single parameter. You need to specify offset value as well.

```
int fileOffset  = BitConverter.ToInt32(byteSource, 0);
```